# Alert statement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have a look at the piece of code. I am trying for an animation, but somehow it is not possible. I just changed to check for the alert statement, but still I am unable to get that.

I am doing something silly, I will put my codes here, help me out.

Intended functionality is I will click on an image, after that it should animate, but at this point it must display the alert statement.

This part is from html.

```
<div class="content_area">
    <div class="image5" id="5" style="display:none;width:40%;height:80%;">
        <img src="img/5.jpg" id="leftImage">
    </div>
    <div class="image6" id="6" style="display:none;width:40%;height:80%;">
        <img src="img/6.jpg" id="leftImage">
    </div>
    <div class="image7" id="7" style="display:none;width:40%;height:80%;">
        <img src="img/7.jpg" id="leftImage">
    </div>
    <div class="image8" id="8" style="display:none;width:40%;height:80%;">
        <img src="img/8.jpg" id="leftImage">
    </div>
    <div class="image9" id="9" style="display:none;width:40%;height:80%;">
        <img src="img/9.jpg" id="leftImage">
    </div>
    <div class="image10" id="10" style="display:none;width:40%;height:80%;">
        <img src="img/10.jpg" id="leftImage">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-wrapper" id="scrollimage" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;line-height:0;">
        <img src="img/gallery/5.jpg" class="div-image1" id="5"/><img src="img/gallery/6.jpg" class="div-image2" id="6"/><img src="img/gallery/7.jpg" class="div-image3" id="7"/><img src="img/gallery/8.jpg" class="div-image4" id="8"/><img src="img/gallery/9.jpg" class="div-image5" id="9"/><img src="img/gallery/10.jpg" class="div-image6" id="10"/>
    </div>
    <div class="div-slide-effect">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript part from custom.js

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('.div-image1').click(function () {
            alert("Hi");
            $('.image5').show();
            $('.gallery-wrapper').hide();

            //  $("#"+plan_image_id_slct).animate({ width: content_width-500 , height: 600 }, 500, "linear");
        });
    });


Here is the full custom.js
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* SLIDE OUT CONTENTS FOR THE PAGES (WORLD ABOVE THE WORLD)
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

$(window).load(function () {
$('.left_black_out').animate({
     left: '225'
 }, 1000);
});

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* MOUSE HOVER CHANGE OPACITY : HOME PAGE
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('.div-image').each(function() {
                $(this).hover(
                    function() {
                        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: .8}, 800);
                    },
                   function() {
                       $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 800);
                   })
                });
        });

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* CLICK AND INCREASE IMAGE SIZE : PLAN PAGE
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('.plan-image').click(function() {

var plan_image_id_not_slct = 0;
var plan_image_id_slct = $(this).attr('id');
var current_width = $("#"+plan_image_id_slct).width();
var content_width = $(".content_area").width();

if (plan_image_id_slct == 1 )
    {
        $('.plan-wrapper').hide();
        /*$('.leftpart-plan').show();*/
        $('.leftpart-plan').show().animate({ width: content_width-400 , height: 600 }, 500, "linear");
        /*plan_image_id_not_slct = 2; 
        $("#"+plan_image_id_not_slct).fadeOut();
        $("#"+plan_image_id_slct).animate({ width: content_width-500 , height: 600 }, 500, "linear");*/

    }
else
    {
        $('.plan-wrapper').hide();
        $('.rightpart-plan').show().animate({ width: content_width-400 , height: 600 , left : '600px' }, 500);;
        /*plan_image_id_not_slct = 1;
        $("#"+plan_image_id_not_slct).fadeOut();
        $("#"+plan_image_id_slct).animate({ width: content_width-500 , height: 600 , left : 400 }, 500);*/
    }





});
});

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* CLICK AND DECREASE IMAGE SIZE : PLAN PAGE
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('.leftpart-plan').click(function() {
    $('.plan-wrapper').show();
    $('.leftpart-plan').hide();
});

$('.rightpart-plan').click(function(){
    $('.plan-wrapper').show();
    $('.rightpart-plan').hide();
});
});


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* CLICK AND START SLIDE SHOW : HOME PAGE
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var $slideid = 0;
    function slideSwitch() {

         $('.div-slide-effect').css({left : '-700px'});
         $('.div-slide-effect').animate({left: '1800px'}, 2000);
        var $active = $('.slideshow IMG.active');
        if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('.slideshow IMG:last');
        var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next(): $('.slideshow IMG:first');
    $active.addClass('last-active');
   $next.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('active').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 2000, function() {$active.removeClass('active last-active');});


}    
   /*Hide gallery image and start Slide*/
   $('.div-image').click(function() {
         $('.div-image').hide();
         $('.slideshow').show();
        $slideid = setInterval(function(){slideSwitch()},6000);
  });

    /*show gallery image and stop Slide*/
    $('.slideshow').click(function() {
        $('.div-image').show();
        $('.slideshow').hide();
        clearInterval($slideid);
        });
});

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Menu slide in
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

$(document).ready(function()
{

$('.left_black').click(function()
{
    $(this).animate( {left:-50}, {duration:1000, easing:"easeOutQuart"} );
    $('.left_black_out').animate( {left:0}, {duration:1000, easing:"easeOutQuart"} );   
});

// for Second menu In 
$('.left_black_out img').click(function()
{

    if( $('.left_black_out').css('left') == '225px' ){
        $('.left_black_out').animate({ left : -660},{duration:1000, easing:"easeOutQuart"});

    } else {
        $('.left_black_out').animate({ left : 225},{duration:1000, easing:"easeOutQuart"});
    }

});


});

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  LOADER
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
'use strict';

$('body').prepend('<div id="spinningSquaresG"><div id="spinningSquaresG_1" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_2" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_3" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_4" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_5" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_6" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_7" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_8" class="spinningSquaresG"></div></div>');
});

jQuery(window).load(function($){

    jQuery('body').find('#spinningSquaresG').remove();
    jQuery('.content').animate({'opacity' : '1'}, 500);

});
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  MOBILE NAV
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
'use strict';

    $('#mobile-nav').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 200);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('header').toggleClass('active');
            $('#mobile-nav').toggleClass('active'); 
        }, 200);    
    });

});
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  NAVIGATION ACTIVE
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
'use strict';

    $('nav a[href^="' + location.pathname.split("/")[2] + '"]').addClass('active').parents('li').children('a').addClass('active');

});
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  SLIDER
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
'use strict';

    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
      speed: 500,
      timeout: 4000,
      pager: true
    });

});
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  ISOTOPE
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(window).load(function($){
'use strict';

    jQuery('ul.grid').isotope({
        itemSelector : 'li',
        transformsEnabled : false
    });

    jQuery('.filters a').click(function(){
        var filter = jQuery(this).attr('data-href');
        jQuery('.filters li').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass('active');
        jQuery('ul.grid').isotope({filter: filter});
        jQuery(window).trigger('resize');
        return false;
    });

    jQuery(window).smartresize(function(){
        jQuery('ul.grid').isotope('reLayout');
    });

    jQuery(window).trigger('resize');

    jQuery('header').height( jQuery(document).height() );

    jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        jQuery('header').height( jQuery(window).height() );
        setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery('header').height( jQuery(document).height() );
        }, 900);
    });

});
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  HOVER DIR
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
'use strict';

    $(function(){
        $('ul.grid.portfolio li, .more-hover').each( function() {$(this).hoverdir();} );
    });

});
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  GALLERY HOVER
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
'use strict';

    $('.gallery.animate li').hover(function(){
        $('.gallery li').not(this).stop().animate({'opacity' : '0.3'}, 200);
    }, function(){
        $('.gallery li').stop().animate({'opacity' : '1'}, 200);
    });
});
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  AJAX PORTFOLIO
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
'use strict';

    $('body').on('click', 'ul.grid li a, .gallery-wrapper a', function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        $('.content').prepend('<div id="spinningSquaresG"><div id="spinningSquaresG_1" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_2" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_3" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_4" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_5" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_6" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_7" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_8" class="spinningSquaresG"></div></div>');

        $.get(url, function(data){
            var filtered = jQuery(data).filter('section').removeClass('content');

            $(filtered).find(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
              speed: 500,
              timeout: 4000,
              pager: true
            });

            $(filtered).imagesLoaded(function(){
                $('ul.grid, .gallery-wrapper').animate({'left' : '-100%', 'opacity' : '0'}, function(){
                    $('ul.grid, .gallery-wrapper').css('max-height', '0px');
                    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 200);
                    $('#loader').html(filtered);
                    $('#spinningSquaresG').remove();
                    $('#loader').slideDown(function(){
                        jQuery(window).trigger('resize');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        return false;
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.post-nav', function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        $('.content').prepend('<div id="spinningSquaresG"><div id="spinningSquaresG_1" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_2" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_3" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_4" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_5" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_6" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_7" class="spinningSquaresG"></div><div id="spinningSquaresG_8" class="spinningSquaresG"></div></div>');

        $.get(url, function(data){
            var filtered = jQuery(data).filter('section').removeClass('content');

            $(filtered).find(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
              speed: 500,
              timeout: 4000,
              pager: true
            });

            $(filtered).imagesLoaded(function(){
                $('#loader').animate({'left' : '-100%', 'opacity' : '0'}, function(){
                    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 200);
                    $('#spinningSquaresG').remove();
                    $('#loader').html(filtered).animate({'left' : '0', 'opacity' : '1'});
                });
            });
        });
        return false;
    });

    $('body').on('click', 'a.close', function(){

        $('#loader').slideUp(function(){
            $('ul.grid, .gallery-wrapper').css('max-height', '');
            $('ul.grid, .gallery-wrapper').animate({'left' : '0', 'opacity' : '1'},function(){
                jQuery(window).trigger('resize');
            });
        });

        return false;
    });

});
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  VERTICAL GALLERY
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(window).load(function($){
'use strict';

if(jQuery('#vertical').length > 0){
    var sly = new Sly(jQuery('#vertical'), {
        horizontal: 1,
        itemNav: 'basic',
        smart: 1,
        activateOn: 'click',
        mouseDragging: 1,
        touchDragging: 1,
        releaseSwing: 1,
        startAt: 0,
        scrollBy: 1,
        activatePageOn: 'click',
        speed: 300,
        elasticBounds: 1,
        dragHandle: 1,
        dynamicHandle: 1,
        clickBar: 1,
    }).init();

    jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        sly.reload();
    });
}

});
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  VEIW BACKGROUND
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
'use strict';

$('.view-background').click(function(){
    if( $('.content').css('left') == '0px' ){
        $('.content').animate({'left' : '-100%', 'opacity' : '0'});
        $('.view-background').html('<i class="icon-eye-open icon-2x"></i>');
    } else {
        $('.content').animate({'left' : '0', 'opacity' : '1'});
        $('.view-background').html('<i class="icon-eye-close icon-2x"></i>');
    }
    return false;
});

});
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  TABS
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
'use strict';

        $('.tab-container').easytabs();

});
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  ALERTS
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
'use strict';

        $('.alert i').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().slideUp();
        });

});
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  ACCORDION
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
'use strict';

        $('.accordion > dd.active').show();

        $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
            if( $(this).parent().hasClass('active') ){
                $(this).parents('.accordion').find('dt').removeClass('active');
                $(this).parents('.accordion').find('dd').removeClass('active').slideUp();
                return false;
            } else {
                $(this).parents('.accordion').find('dt').removeClass('active');
                $(this).parents('.accordion').find('dd').removeClass('active').slideUp();
                $(this).parent().addClass('active').next().addClass('active').slideDown();
                return false;
            }
        });

});
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  CONTACT FORM
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
'use strict';

    //CONTACT FORM
        $('#contactform').submit(function(){

            var action = $(this).attr('action');

            $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
            $('#message').hide();

            $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');

            $.post(action, {
                name: $('#name').val(),
                email: $('#email').val(),
                website: $('#website').val(),
                comments: $('#comments').val()
            },
                function(data){
                    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                    $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                    if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');
                    $(window).trigger('resize');
                }
            );

            });

            return false;

        });

});
/*         */
/*  FOR GALLERY 

/**/
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('.div-image1').click(function() {
alert("Hi");
$('.image5').show();
    $('.gallery-wrapper').hide();    

  //  $("#"+plan_image_id_slct).animate({ width: content_width-500 , height: 600 }, 500, "linear");
});
});
```

here is the LOG

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'responsiveSlides' custom.js:193
Failed to load resource file:///C:/Users/MAIBAMA/Desktop/imperial_dev/font/manksans-medium.woff
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'isotope' custom.js:206
Failed to load resource file:///C:/Users/MAIBAMA/Desktop/imperial_dev/js-disclaimer/jquery.min.map
Failed to load resource file:///C:/Users/MAIBAMA/Desktop/imperial_dev/js-disclaimer/jquery.min.map
Failed to load resource file:///C:/Users/MAIBAMA/Desktop/imperial_dev/js-disclaimer/jquery.min.map
```

Comment: sry about that just edited

Comment: See in JS code below :)

Comment: Are you really mixing `jQuery` and `$`?

Comment: @ kuldeep.kamboj where is the js code

Comment: Press `F12` in your browser, and see if you get any errors after clicking

Comment: Did you added the JQuery plugin?

Comment: I checked and its working perfectly along with alert messages and animation.

Comment: whats the trick R Ajay ,its really irritating me 
can u help out

Comment: are u sure u clicking image id - ('.div-image1') its works fine in fiddle..http://jsfiddle.net/8ec7Q/

Comment: @N.NIhar, Im commenting out on another commentator who asking where is alert code, Now he seems to remove his comment. :)

Comment: If you can check on your javascript debugger like firebug to check what error are comes during page load, click events.

Comment: Please don't use multiple `jQuery(document).ready(function()`. Use only one and all your code should come under this or you can use functions to separate

Comment: @ Neha sure am clicking the right image

Comment: @ thefourtheye
one pressing the F12 key check the log i had put

Comment: Check this if its help just few cleanups http://jsfiddle.net/8ec7Q/2/

Comment: @ Neha ,thanks so much yeah its working ... :)
can u tellm e where was I wrong ??
U seriously saved a lot of my time.

Comment: well its few js syntax erros .. if u want to chk copy ur old code in jsfiddle and do jsHint it will prompt all errors line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the few cleans up in js its have some syntax errors..
[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ec7Q/2)

for e.g. this need to

```
  $(this).stop().animate({opacity: .8}, 800);
```

change to this

```
  $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.8}, 800);
```

There are few more check link.